# create 'infinite' slideshow effect with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an infinity slideshow and have tried numerous attempts to make it infinite by moving the container. You can see that the transitions are working but the issue is when you get to the end you can see it goes back to the start. Can anyone advise how to create the infinite effect?

[JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0t4e87mL/1/) if people prefer that, or else see code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const numSlides = 6;
  let index = 0;
  $('.next-arrow').click(function() {
    const slideWidth = $('.card').outerWidth(true);
    index += 1;
    if (index === numSlides) {
      index = 0;
    }
    $('.card').css('transform', `translateX(-${slideWidth * index}px)`)
  });

  $('.prev-arrow').click(function() {
    const slideWidth = $('.card').outerWidth(true);
    index -= 1;
    if (index < 0) {
      index = numSlides - 1;
    }
    $('.card').css('transform', `translateX(-${slideWidth * index}px)`);
  });

});
```

```css
.slideshow-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
}

.four {
  background: orange;
}

.five {
  background: pink;
}

.six {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slideshow-wrapper'>
  <div class="card one"></div>
  <div class="card two"></div>
  <div class="card three"></div>
  <div class="card four"></div>
  <div class="card five"></div>
  <div class="card six"></div>
</div>

<button class="prev-arrow">PREV</button>
<button class="next-arrow">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: You create an infinite slideshow by moving the first `.card` to the end each time.  This can be shown by replacing your entire `.next-arrow` click handler with just `var wrapper = $(".slideshow-wrapper");wrapper.find(".card:first").appendTo(wrapper);`   However, this *removes* the animation. So I haven't added this as an answer as I believe it is incomplete for your final requirements (but you might be able to expand on this to add an animation (my solution was very klunky))

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m, but I need to retain the animation.

Comment: Well, it was more about you/someone adding the animation to the 'move .card to the end' than "retaining" the existing animation.

Answer (score 1):

I created code for the "next" button, using the order attribute of the flexbox. I think the code speaks for itself but I added a few comments in there.

I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the functionality for the "previous" button yourself ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.next-arrow').click(function() {
    const slideWidth = $('.card').outerWidth(true);
    const anim = (slideWidth) * -1 + "px";

    $('.slideshow-wrapper')
      .animate({'marginLeft' : anim}, 500, function() {
        /* When animation is ready, reorganize the order of elements */
        $(".card").each( function(index, element) {
          const currentOrder = $(element).css("order");
          let newOrder = currentOrder - 1;
          if (newOrder === 0) {
            newOrder = 6;
            /* When the first item is moved, reset the margin */
            $('.slideshow-wrapper').css("margin-left", "0px");
          }
          $(element).css("order", newOrder);
        });
      });
  });

  $('.prev-arrow').click(function() {
    const slideWidth = $('.card').outerWidth(true);
  });

});
```

```css
.slideshow-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  order: 1;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
    order: 2;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
    order: 3;
}

.four {
  background: orange;
    order: 4;
}

.five {
  background: pink;
    order: 5;
}

.six {
  background: green;
    order: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slideshow-wrapper'>
  <div class="card one"></div>
  <div class="card two"></div>
  <div class="card three"></div>
  <div class="card four"></div>
  <div class="card five"></div>
  <div class="card six"></div>
</div>

<button class="prev-arrow">PREV</button>
<button class="next-arrow">NEXT</button>
```